# Determine if an Estimator is Biased (Unusual Expectation Expression)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. with a common density function:

$$f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$$
for $0<x<1$ and $\theta>0$.  So this is $\operatorname{BETA}(\theta,1)$ distribution.

Given this Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) for $\theta$:  $$\hat \theta=\frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(X_i)}$$

**Determine if $\hat\theta$ is biased.  If it is biased, could you redefine it to make it unbiased?**

Unfortunately, this is where I get stuck; I have no idea how to evaluate the expectation of $\hat\theta$. $$\operatorname E\left( \frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(X_i)} \right)$$

How does one calculate this?

Comment: Very closely related to [_this_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649775/mle-maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-beta-distribution/2649846#2649846) recent Question. Not voting to say it's a duplicate, but you might get something useful from the Comments there. Short version: $\hat \theta$ is biased.

Comment: I suspected that, but the issue is that I'm not really sure how to mathematically show that it is.

Comment: Nor am I. I have used simulation to convince myself that neither MLE or MOM is unbiased. Wikipedia is not much help on unbiasedness. Haven't looked at Bayes'.

Comment: It is similar to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619937/expected-value-for-a-combination-of-iid-from-fx-theta-frac-theta-x and the solution is almost the same!

Comment: If you have any question on the question I linked to I can expand here.

Comment: I tried it, but I ended up with some unusual distribution for the $Y=ln(X_i)$.  I ended up with a PDF looking like this: $$f_Y(y)=\theta e^{y\theta}$$ where $-\infty<y<0$.  Not sure where to go with that.

Comment: If you just want to show biasness apply Jensen and calculate $E(log x) = -1/\theta$.

Comment: I attempted that but ended up with an inconclusive result since all it ends up showing is that the expected value of $\hat\theta$ is less than or equal to the parameter we're trying to estimate.

Comment: $E(\hat\theta) > \theta$ because $f(t)= \frac 1 t$ is strictly convex. Thus it is biased.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  Thank you very much.  But now there's that second part of the question.

Comment: Calculate the bias and subtract it. To calculate it you first calculate the distribution of logx, then you calculate the distribution of the sum of two logs with convolution and use then induction for $n$. You get the distribution of $log x_1 + log x_2 + \cdots +log x_n$. When you have the distribution of $Y$ you can compute the distribution of $\frac 1 Y$ using $\mathbb P(\frac 1 Y \leq t) = \mathbb P(Y \geq \frac 1 t) = 1 - \mathbb P(Y < \frac 1 t) = 1- F(\frac 1 t) $ then derive. This can be done for $Y,t >0$.

Comment: This is what I think. I'm not an expert in probability and statistics. You could create a new question to ask for $\operatorname E\left( \frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(X_i)} \right)$ and see what experts say.

Answer (score 2):

Define,
$$
Y = -\ln X,
$$
thus
$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y\le y)=\mathbb{P}(X\ge e^{-y}) = 1-F_X(e^{-y}),
$$
hence, 
$$
f_X(x) = f_X(e^{-y})e^{-y}=\theta e^{-y (\theta - 1)}e^{-y} = \theta e^{-y\theta}, \quad y>0.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
 - \sum_{i=1}^n\ln X_i \sim \mathcal{G}amma(n,\theta).
$$
As such, 
$$
\frac{n}{-\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i} \sim n\times \mathcal{I}nv\mathcal{G}amma(n, \theta),
$$
then the expectation is
$$
\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_n] = \frac{n}{n-1}\theta > \theta,
$$
namely,
$$
\tilde{\theta}_n = \frac{n-1}{n}\hat{\theta}_n,
$$
is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.