# Distribution of Maximum Likelihood Estimator for $f(x) = \theta / x^{\theta + 1}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Assume $X_1, ..., X_n$ has a probability density function $$f(x|\theta) = \frac{\theta}{x^{\theta + 1}}$$

for $1 < x < \infty$ and $\theta > 1$.

I found that the MLE is $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \text{log}(x_i)}$$

Now I have to find the distribution of $T = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{log}(x_i)$. I think a good way to do this is to start by writing $$f(x|\theta) = \theta e^{-\theta \log(x)}$$
and then consider $\log(\theta e^{-\theta \log(x)})$, but I do not see anything special here, even if I think there is something with an exponential distribution. Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to specify the support of $X$.

Comment: Thank you, I just did it!

Comment: Unfortunately, $$\int_{x = 1}^\infty \frac{\theta}{x^{\theta - 1}} \, dx = \left[\frac{\theta x^{2-\theta}}{2 - \theta}\right]_{x=1}^\infty = \frac{\theta}{\theta - 2}, \quad \theta > 2.$$  Therefore, this does not define a proper density.  Are you sure it is not $$f(x \mid \theta) = \frac{\theta}{x^{\theta + 1}}, \quad 1 < x < \infty?$$

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'm sorry about that. I once again edited the message

Comment: Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1967444/321264

Comment: Thank you! I hope to be able to get the next one right now.